# inno setup - batch change InstallDircation

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I am trying to run a batch file right before the installation begins,
Just after the user chooses the component he wants to install.

fortunately, I don't build it from basic, I have a ready iss file which depending on the component runs a batch file that you have created already.

In the batch file I trying to change the directory of the installer to specific one.
I tried to do so as I set **INSTALLBINDIR** and **appfolder** to my directory but it haven't work.

Do you know the variables I need to set so the installer will install where I want?

**Edit:**
I found out that I don't need to use a batch file.

To fixed a position to file you just need to put your Directory in the DestDir in **[files]**

Comment: `{src}` is the constant for installer directory (if I understood you right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the install directory directly from a sub script/program run from the installer.
You will need to set the `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text` in `[Code]` to the new value.

Alternatively, you can use a `{code:...}` constant for the `DefaultDirName` directive to get a suitable value to start with.